# How do I connect to the database MS Access?

Tags: java, maven, connection, ucanaccess

I have a Maven Project and I am trying to create a connection to my MS Access db. The problem is that it does not open.

I do not receive any type of error, but the program remains active without returning the connection. I tried to stay on hold two hours but nothing. The `databaseProduction` WellSys is linked to `ProdWheelTableMasterSys` and `WhellDemand`.

My code is:

```
package com.sealed.air.SealedAir;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String conex = "jdbc:ucanaccess://";
        String url = "C:/DB/ProductionWhellSys.accdb";
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conex+url);
            System.out.println("Connected");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the result in the console is:

> ```
> Connecting
> ```

My DB MS access properties:

[image]

console.bat output:

[image]

saved query in Access:

[image]

I have tried changing the "" in '' but I do not understand because it gives me the same error. Another mistake I found was:

```
Error message was: unexpected token: , required: )
```

Comment: Where is your `Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver"); ` line? See [tutorial](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html).

Comment: if I add I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you reported two different issues:

- the first one is that the "the program remains active without
  returning the connection" but seeing your App test, this doesn't seem due to ucanaccess... did you set Openexclusive=true?